# $n_1n_2...n_{11}-1$ is a product of two consecutive natural numbers.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Prove that there exist distinct, pairwise coprime natural numbers $n_1,n_2,...,n_{11}$ such that $n_1n_2...n_{11}-1$ is a product of two consecutive natural numbers.

Let $N = n_1n_2...n_{11}$ My approach was to firstly notice that none of the $n_1n_2...n_{11}$ is an even integer, otherwise $n_1n_2...n_{11}-1$ would be odd. Then I thought about using $CRT$ \begin{align} N&=1\mod x, \\ N&=1 \mod x+1,\end{align} $x,x+1$ to conssecutive natural numbers. By $CRT$ we know that this system of congruences has a solution. Now I want to prove that the sol. is $0$ $\mod x(x+1)$ and deduce that $n_1n_2...n_{11}-1 = x(x+1)$ is true. How to proceed? Any help appreciated.

Comment: Are you just looking for an example?  Why not take $n_1, \cdots, n_{10}=1$ and $n_{11}=7$?

Comment: What are $n_1,\ldots, n_{11}$?

Comment: I' m sorry I forgot about the fact that all the numbers are different. Anyway nice solution.

Comment: This is more or less the same as [your prior question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3973168/fx-has-2020-divisors-for-infinately-many-x-in-bbb-n),  You just want $n$ such that $f(n)=n^2+n+1$ has at least $11$ prime factors.  In this case it is clear that $f(n)\equiv 0 \pmod p$ is solvable for infinitely many $p$, as the discriminant, $-3$ is a square for infinitely many primes.

Comment: How does it imply that $n_1...n_{11}-1$ is a product of two consecutive numbers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume you want to avoid the trivial solutions where some of the $n_i$ are $=1$.

**Claim.** Let $S$ be the set of all primes $p$ for which  $x^2+x+1\equiv 0\pmod{p}$ has a solution. Then $S$ is infinite.

*Proof.* Assume otherwise. Then  $S=\{p_1,\ldots, p_n\}$ is a finite set of primes. Let $y=p_1\cdots p_n$ and $z=y(y+1)+1$. Then  $z\ge 1\cdot 2+1=3>1$. Let $p$ be a prime divisor of $z$. Then $p\in S$ as witnessed by $x=y$. But then $z\equiv 1\pmod p$, contradicting $p\mid z$. $\square$

Pick $11$ primes $p_1,\ldots , p_{11}\in S$. For each of them, find $x_i$ with $x_i(x_i+1)\equiv -1\pmod {p_i}$ (which is possible because $p_i\in S$). Use CRT to find a natural number $x$ such that $x\equiv x_i\pmod {p_i}$.
Then $x(x+1)\equiv x_i(x_i+1)\equiv -1\pmod{p_i}$ for $1\le i\le 11$. So the number $N:=x(x+1)+1$ has at least $11$ different prime divisors. Thus $N$ can clearly be factored into $11$ pairwise co-prime numbers $>1$ (which are a fortiori pairwise distinct). Of course, $11$ plays no special role and can be replaced by any natural number.

---

*Remark:* In my first write-up, I had a wrong expression in $x$ instead of $x^3+x+1$. With the correct expression, $x^2+x+1$, it is of course clear from $x^3-1=(x-1)(x^2+x+1)$ that $x^2+x+1\equiv 0\pmod p$ implies $x^3\equiv 1\pmod p$, and conversely any non-trivial solution of the latter is a solution of the former. From this we read off that $S$ consists precisely of $3$ and the primes $p\equiv 1\pmod 3$. (So essentially the proof of the claim above turns into a proof of the fact that there are infinitely many such primes). It comes to no surprise that the solution by @Oleg567 involves the first such primes (only $1117$ is larger).

Comment: How does the fact that $N$ can be factored into $11$ pairwise coprime numbers > 1 tells us that $n_1...n_{11}-1$ is a product of two consecutive numbers?

Comment: @somerndguy $N$ is produced as a number one more than the product of successive numbers ($x$ and $x{+}1$).

Comment: I understand, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The following is an answer to the old version of the question, where $n_{i}$ are not necessarily distinct:

As lulu comments, you may take the the example $n_{1},...,n_{10} = 1$ and $n_{11} = 7$.

Note that in the same fashion, it is possible to prove in general that there are infinitely many.

Take $M=k(k+1)+1$, for any $k$, with $n_{1},...n_{m-1}=1$, and $n_{m}=M$.

Comment: Moreover, for $M=\prod p_i^{a_i}$, we can replace certain of the $n_{j\le 11}=1,M$ with various divisors of $M$ providing we select divisors such that no $p_i$ appears as a factor in more than one selected divisor. For example, for $M=9\times 10+1=91$, we can replace one of the $n_j=1$ and $91$ itself with $7,13$.

Comment: I' m sorry I forgot about the fact that all the numbers are different. Anyway thanks for help..

Answer (score 1):

One of (not too large) examples:
$$
n= 303750157,
$$
$$
n(n+1) = 3 \times 7 \times 13 \times 19 \times 31 \times 37 \times 43 \times 61 \times 67 \times 79 \times 1117 -1,
$$
where all the factors in RHS are prime numbers.

Another examples:

$n = 540178291$,

$n = 876805855$,

$n = 956495446$,

$\ldots$

Comment: How did u find this answer?

Comment: @somerndguy: just factoring numbers of the form $n^2+n+1$, using small prime factors.